Tuning advisor ignores old query store queries
I'm using the SQL Server database tuning advisor (DTA) to tune a database using a workload stored in the query store. The query_store_query view records more than 38 thousand events.
SELECT * 
FROM sys.query_store_query;

Most of the queries are several months old. When I run the DTA using GUI, it considers just a few of the most recent queries. However, I mainly need to analyze the old queries. I have also tried the cmd:
dta -S localhost\sql2019 -D db_name -E -iq -l 10000 -s "TuningSession" -of C:\TuningOutput.sql

But the output is still the same. It processes just a few recent SQL commands. How can an ancient workload from a Query store be analyzed using DTA?

I've set up an Extended Event to track what statement DTA uses to grab the data from Query Store and got this (comments and formatting mine)
WITH X
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 50000 /* matches the -n parameter */
        query.query_text_id
      , query.object_id
      , DB_ID () AS dbid
      , AVG (sts.count_executions) AS exec_count
      , query.last_compile_batch_sql_handle
      , SUM (sts.count_executions * sts.avg_duration) AS total_duration
      , SUM (sts.count_executions * sts.avg_rowcount) AS total_rows
      , query.query_id
    FROM
        sys.query_store_runtime_stats AS sts
        JOIN sys.query_store_plan AS pln
            ON sts.plan_id = pln.plan_id
        JOIN sys.query_store_query AS query
            ON pln.query_id = query.query_id
    WHERE
        query.last_execution_time > DATEADD (HOUR, -10000, GETUTCDATE ()) /* matches the -l (lowercase "L") parameter */
        AND sts.last_execution_time > DATEADD (HOUR, -720, GETUTCDATE ()) /* <-- this is the problem */
    GROUP BY
        query.query_text_id, query.object_id, query.last_compile_batch_sql_handle, query.query_id
    HAVING SUM (sts.count_executions) >= 1
    ORDER BY SUM (sts.count_executions * sts.avg_duration) DESC
)
SELECT
    X.object_id
  , X.dbid
  , X.exec_count
  , querytext.query_text_id
  , CONVERT (varchar(130), querytext.statement_sql_handle, 1) AS statement_sql_handle
  , CONVERT (varchar(130), X.last_compile_batch_sql_handle, 1) AS last_compile_batch_sql_handle
  , X.total_rows
  , X.query_id
  , querytext.query_sql_text
FROM
    X
    INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text AS querytext
        ON X.query_text_id = querytext.query_text_id
ORDER BY X.total_duration DESC

For command
.\DTA.EXE -S localhost -D MyDatabase -E -iq -l 10000 -n 50000 -s "TuningSession" -of C:\TuningOutput.sql

The limiting filter is on the sts.last_execution_time and it's not affected by any parameter I found.
The only workaround I can currently think of is to restore the database to a different server where you can change the system time.

Changing the system time is an interesting idea. Unfortunately, I cannot change the system time in our testing environment, and the database is too large to be moved somewhere else.

You may want to include the following options in your call to the dta utility:

-n - This is the number of events to read. By default, this is set to 1000, so DTA picks the top 1000 events by duration and tunes them. If you know there are ~38,000 events, then maybe set this to 38000
-A - This is the total time for tuning in minutes. By default, this is 8 hours, so if dta reaches 8 hours tuning time before processing all events, then it stops. Setting -A 0 ensures dta will process until all events are processed (depending on the values of -n and -l).

Your current settings should pick the top 1000 events by duration from the previous 10000 hours, however, it may be that the bulk of these long duration events are not the older ones you're looking for.
More Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/dta/dta-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

None of these parameters helps. Thanks.

You may want to check the Stale Query Threshold (Days) setting in the Query Store configuration under the Database Properties. In my case, it is set to 30 days, which means the Query Store only retains execution data from the past 30 days.

The sys.query_store_query view may include stale queries, but other Query Store views, such as sys.query_store_runtime_stats, do not contain data older than 30 days.
For instance, in my database's Query Store, there is an entry for query ID 8761 in the sys.query_store_query view, but there is no corresponding entry for that query in the sys.query_store_runtime_stats view.

This means you may need to extend the Stale Query Threshold (Days) to cover older data. You may also need to increase the Query Store Retention - Max Size (MB) setting to increase available storage for the query store, depending on your workload though.
You can monitor to figure out the Max Size storage for the database's query store. For example, adding more when it nearly hits the limit. Otherwise, "If data in Query Store hits that limit, Query Store will automatically change state from read-write to read-only and stop collecting new data."

Unfortunately, this is not a problem since the Stale query threshold is set to 720.

Unfortunately, none of the suggestions helped. Finally, we decided to collect the SQL commands from the Query store and run them again. We use the following SQL command.
SELECT 
    qt.query_id,
    qp.plan_id,
    qt.query_hash,
    qt.query_parameterization_type_desc,
    qtt.query_sql_text AS QueryText,
    qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan,  
    SUM(rs.count_executions) AS ExecutionCount,
    AVG(rs.avg_duration / 1000.0) AS AverageDurationMs,
    (SUM(rs.count_executions) * AVG(rs.avg_duration / 1000.0)) AS TotalDuration
FROM sys.query_store_query qt
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_plan qp ON qt.query_id = qp.query_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs ON qp.plan_id = rs.plan_id
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qtt ON qt.query_text_id = qtt.query_text_id
GROUP BY qt.query_id, qp.plan_id, qt.query_hash, qt.query_parameterization_type_desc, qtt.query_sql_text, qp.query_plan
ORDER BY TotalDuration DESC;

We were able to read the parameter values from the query plan. It is not the perfect solution; however, the workload can be at least simulated that way.
